# Code to detect all words that start with an X in a array :Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, syntax

```
import urllib.request
import csv
import http.client
import bs4
import Data
import re


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from Data import DA

#Extracting Html code from the URL
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.apecbraking.co.uk/catalogue/frictionParts/range/783854") as url:
        D = url.read()






#HTML Code *

soup = BeautifulSoup(D)     
Table = (soup.table)        
soup = (Table.get_text())   



#Creates 'APEC.csv' 

file = open("APEC.csv", "w")              
file.write(soup)                          
file.close()                              
print('Written')                          


# Set the Data into a list so it can be refered back to later on e.g searching for only words with certain letter
# from there they can be seperated from one list into categories (Variables)

newRow = []                                                                                                       
with open('APEC.csv') as f:                                                                                       
    reader = csv.reader(f)                                                                                        
    for row in reader:                                                                                            
        print()                                                                                                     
    #New List                                                                                                     
    newRow.append(row)                                                                                            


print(re.findall('A'))
```

> > Anyone explain to me whats wrong i do not understand tbh :/
>
> **Error**
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/B8/Desktop/Task/TaskOriginal.py", line 49, in <module>
>     print(newRow.findall('A'))
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findall'
> ```
>
> Ignore had to add more detail to update
>   sdfdsffffffffffffffffffffddfsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: Isn't [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) part of the regular expression (`re`) library? You are calling `list.findAll()`.

Comment: ill try to import the re library now

Comment: That still won't help. It's not `<LIST>.findall()`, it's `re.findall()`.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post, as it looks horribly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
with open('yourfile') as f:
    new_list = [row for row in f if row.startswith('A')]
```

Comment: yours works but its only find one word instead of finding all of them

Comment: thats odd.. try printing the lines to see if they are divided as you expect

Comment: < it still prints ['A1 [2010-]\n'] and there are over 5 of these starting with the letter a >

Comment: it prints it with this brackets? if so, try if row.startswith('[A')

Comment: That does prints nothing if i add an '['

Answer (score 0):

Your `newRow` has type `list`. That has no method associated with this type. You can get list of all available methods for this type by typing `help(list)` in python console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the regular expression library

```
import re
```

OR just try this snippet of code

```
print([item for item in newRow if item[0]=='A'])
```